# Issues in Training line-based OCR by dividing data on IAM Handwriting Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, ocr

I am beginner level at deep learning who has theoritical knowledge but less practical work and I am currently working on final year OCR project using the IAM Handwriting dataset and looking to train using deep learning technique possibly, transfer learning.
[image: Used folders for project]
Above, the green color represents the used directory, where forms has full scale image, lines has image of each line in full scale image and ascii has lines.txt where the information like imageid, lineid, bounding box and text content of each line. I need help for training this information, so that after giving full scale image it will give all the text inside the image.

Till now, I have extracted the text of each line from lines.txt, relative path of fullscale images and relative path of each line of images in Google Collab.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from PIL import Image
import os

lines_txt_path = os.path.join("drive","MyDrive","datasets","ascii","lines.txt")
lines_folder_path = os.path.join("drive","MyDrive","datasets","lines")

#Read the content of lines.txt
with open(lines_txt_path, "r") as lines_file:
    lines = lines_file.readlines()

dataset, vocab, max_len = [], set(), 0
for line in tqdm(lines):
  if line.startswith('#'):
    continue
  print("Original Line : ",line)
  line_split = line.split(' ')
  form_id = line_split[0] #Example: 'a01-000u-00'
  folder1 = form_id[:3] # Example: 'a01'
  file_name_lines = f'{form_id}.png' # Example:'a01-000u-00.png'
  form_id = form_id[0:-3] # from a01-000u-00 to a01-000u
  file_name_FullImage = f'{form_id}.png'
  label = line_split[-1].rstrip('\n')

  #replace '|' with ' ' in label
  label = label.replace('|',' ')

  #determining the folder structure
  if 'a'<= folder1[0] <= 'd':
    folder_structure = 'formsA-D'
  elif 'e' <= folder1[0] <= 'h':
    folder_structure = 'formsE-H'
  elif 'i' <=folder1[0] <= 'z':
    folder_structure = 'formsI-Z'
  else:
    print(f"Invalid folder for form: {form_id}")
    continue
  print(f"Segmented Text : {label}")
  print(f"filename of Full scale Image : {file_name_FullImage}")
  print(f"filename of sentence : {file_name_lines}")
  #Update relative path to point to full-scale images
  rel_path_full = os.path.join("drive","MyDrive","datasets",folder_structure, file_name_FullImage)

  if not os.path.exists(rel_path_full):
    print(f"File not found : {rel_path_full}")
    continue
  else:
    print(f"Full Scale image exist : {rel_path_full}")

  #path for line segmented image
  rel_path_line = os.path.join(lines_folder_path,folder1,form_id,file_name_lines)

  if not os.path.exists(rel_path_line):
    print(f"File not found : {rel_path_line}")
    continue
  else:
    print(f"Line Segmentation exist : {rel_path_line}")
```

This will gives following output
[image: Out]
So, I am facing problem on how do I actually train this information, like There are two different kind of images, one full image another is each line of that fullImage, and text information of each line. There are also other information in forms.txt with bounding box of text in fullScale image but i have choosen lines.txt. So, I am stuck in this point, how do i actually do it.